# Dot Net Nuke, overriding Admin/Skins/Language

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there a way to override the Admin/Skins in DotNetNuke, 6.2.4 without changing the actual admin Skins?

Ideally I'd like to do it in my Portal/_default/Skins/MySkin folder if possible.

```
~/Admin/Skins/Language.ascx
```

I just want to change the markup in the language module. I can change the css class, but I need to get rid of the flags and replace it with text?

Edit: based on this [link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134633/The-Language-SkinObject-explained) I tried this:

```
<dnn:LANGUAGE runat="server" ID="dnnLANGUAGE" ShowLinks="True" ShowMenu="False" ItemTemplate='<a href="[URL]" class="Language" title="[CULTURE:NATIVENAME]"><span class="Language[SELECTED]">[CULTURE:NAME]</span></a>'/>
```

But the flags are still showing?

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is correct however what I think is happening is that you have only 2 languages, your first language is selected and your second language becomes an alternate, so you would need to set the templates for:
SelectedItemTemplate and AlternateTemplate too so that it works properly.